# How to create a veth pair without ip command in c

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, network-interface

Is there a way to use syscalls like ioctl or netlink to create a veth pair. Generally the common way for veth pair creation is using ip command -

```
ip link add dev veth1 type veth peer name veth2
```

How to create a veth pair in c using ioctl or such syscalls in linux?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain why you want to do this without using the usual command? Did you check the source code of the `ip` command?

Comment: The `ip` command [is open source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git). You could take a look at the code that implements the `ip link add` command and see how it works.